# Sliding drawer layout with EditText handle

Tags: android, android-edittext, handle, slidingdrawer

I am making a Inventory system on android and i am stuck with the search module.
I am planning to make a listview with a slidingdrawer and i want the handle of the sliding drawer to be my search input. The problem is i have an edittext handle and i set my slidingdrawer:allowsingletap="false" but when i tap/click on the handle the keyboard is not showing. is there any solution to achieve this? Here is the code snippet of my xml file.

```
<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:allowSingleTap="false"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle" >


        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="#3FF3FF" 
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Search"
            android:textSize="30dp" />
</SlidingDrawer>
```

(Edited this is the full layoutcode)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/abslayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <AbsoluteLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="262dp"
            android:layout_height="268dp"
            android:layout_x="78dp"
            android:layout_y="187dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/bgasset" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="48dp"
            android:layout_y="50dp"
            android:text="Asset Information "
            android:textSize="40dp" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+android:id/list_asset"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="512dp"
            android:layout_y="100dp"
            android:textAlignment="center" >
        </ListView>
    </AbsoluteLayout>

    <AbsoluteLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="262dp"
            android:layout_height="268dp"
            android:layout_x="78dp"
            android:layout_y="187dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/bgparts" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="48dp"
            android:layout_y="50dp"
            android:text="Parts Information "
            android:textSize="40dp" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+android:id/list_parts"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="514dp"
            android:layout_y="100dp"
            android:textAlignment="center" >
        </ListView>
    </AbsoluteLayout>

    <AbsoluteLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="262dp"
            android:layout_height="268dp"
            android:layout_x="78dp"
            android:layout_y="187dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/bgsoft" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="25dp"
            android:layout_y="50dp"
            android:text="Software Information "
            android:textSize="40dp" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+android:id/list_software"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="514dp"
            android:layout_y="100dp"
            android:textAlignment="center" >
        </ListView>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle"
    android:allowSingleTap="false" 
    android:
    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="#3FF3FF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Search"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:clickable="true"/>

    <AbsoluteLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: please post full code because this layout it self throwing RuntimeException.at least the full layout code.